# Is there a name for a table and child lines?

Tags: database-design, naming-conventions

Many times I have a "parent" table, like invoice, purchase order, billofmaterials, with some general information (name, date, owner, etc) and then many lines, like invoice_lines, purchase_order_lines, etc, with the id of the invoice, purchase, etc.

Usually I display all of them in some kind of header with the general information, and then a table with lines

I usually think like "document", but it is not a document, it could be anythings with detail lines, and I cannot find a proper name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are referring to `Master` (or `Header`) / `Detail`. Wherein the `Parent` is the `Master` (or `Header`) and the `child` is the `Detail` as shown below:

[image]

The `Order` from the `Customer` above is the `Parent` or `Master` while the **individual Items ordered** (or as you termed it as `Lines`) are the `Details`.

So, in your case **Invoice** is the `Master` and **Invoice_lines** is the `Detail` etc.